# javascript FullCalendar eventClick info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); not working correctly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have been trying to get this piece of JavaScript to work correctly but to no avail.  Currently the code should block the current page from following the link and open in another tab/page.  What is currently happening is a new page is opening and link followed but when I go back to the original page it loads the link when it should stay on the page.  Why is this behaviour happening?  See my code below.

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.3.1/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

   <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.3.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

  <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.3.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />


  <script src='/assets/js/demo-to-codepen.js'></script>

  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.3.1/main.min.js'></script>

  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.3.0/main.min.js'></script>

  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.3.0/main.min.js'></script>

  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.3.0/main.min.js'></script>




<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
      defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
      eventColor: '#03a9f3',
      eventTextColor: 'white',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      editable: false,
      events: [
        {
          title: 'TEST URL',
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          start: '2019-12-12T16:00:00'
        },

],
   eventClick: function(info) {
    info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate

    if (info.event.url) {
      window.open(info.event.url);
    }
  }
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

Comment: After seeing the below post I looked into the other css loading on the page and it turns out to be the: 

<link href="/assets/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

link causing the problem.  It loads after the new page opens.  Not quite sure how to resolve the problem. But at least I know what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on codesandbox and it works fine or i may not understand what the problem is.

[image: Edit wonderful-christian-t7xuz]